# why NgModel does not work for mat-checkbox, radio buttons in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of boolean for week days to check what day is selected: `selectedWeekDays: boolean[] = [true,true,true,true,true,true];`

and in .html:

```html
<section>
    <h4>select your days:</h4>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedWeekDays[0]">sat</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedWeekDays[1]">sun</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedWeekDays[2]">mon</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedWeekDays[3]">tue</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedWeekDays[4]">wed</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedWeekDays[5]">thu</mat-checkbox>
  </section>
```

but this error is raised for each mat-checkbox: *Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedWeekDays[2]">sat* ... and so on...
and also this error:
*Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-checkbox'.*

unfortunately, similar above error I had for radio buttons. why this error is raised and how can fix it? best regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported FormsModule in your AppModule.

Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-checkbox'.
This error is due to missing FormModule.

Comment: FormsModule has been imported.

Comment: Share your module code